# databricks delta lake file extension is parquet

Tags: delta-lake

may I know is it correct that the delta lake file extension is *.snappy.parquet ??
I use the code

```
 df.write.format('delta').save(blobpath)
```

any one has the idea ???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct.  Delta is built on top of the Parquet files as storage format, and adds additional capabilities such as transactions, ...

P.S. this is answered in the [Delta's FAQ](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-faq.html#what-format-does-delta-lake-use-to-store-data)